# How show vertical list on Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I am starting in tkinter and I have generated a list with the elements that are in a certain folder and I need to show them in the interface.
I put it in a label but it shows me the elements horizontally and I need it to show one below the other, is there a way to do this?

```
from tkinter import *
from os import listdir

raiz = Tk()
ruta = './imagenes'
fotos = Frame()
fotos.place(x=0,y=0)
fotos.config(bd=10,relief="groove",width="500", height="200")

fotografias = StringVar()
lblfotos = Entry(fotos, textvariable=fotografias)
lblfotos.config(width="75")
lblfotos.place(x=10,y=0)
fotografias.set(listdir(ruta))

raiz.mainloop()
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaEek.png

[1]: P.S. The original idea is that the files in the folder are displayed in the interface and you can interact with them, such as opening or deleting, but I didn't find how, could that be done in tkinter? or maybe in another library?. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `Entry` widget can only hold single line of string.  Use `Listbox` widget instead.  Also avoid using wildcard import and it is better to use `pack()` or `grid()` instead of `place()` in normal case.

Below is an example based on your code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from os import listdir

raiz = tk.Tk()

ruta = './imagenes'

fotos = tk.Frame(raiz, bd=10, relief="groove")
fotos.pack(fill="both", expand=1)

lblfotos = tk.Listbox(fotos, width=30, height=20)
lblfotos.pack(fill="both", expand=1)

for imgfile in listdir(ruta):
    lblfotos.insert("end", imgfile)

raiz.mainloop()
```